# Correct size for the image in Drawable folder

Tags: android, performance, android-imageview

In my App I found that the background used is occupying a large memory space. I planned to keep different size image for different devices of varying size. Now there are 5 folders in my drawables.

drawable-hdpi
drawable-ldpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-xhdpi
drawable-xxhdpi

I need to create the background image which is going to occupy the entire screen. The quality should not be compromised. Based on the above scenario can you please let me know the right size of the image for 5 different folders.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at this in the android developers area http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "quality should not be compromised" is absolutely crucial, then there are much more different dimensions for you to support. There always be some size or aspect ratio differences on devices with similar size, for example 800x480 and 848x480 or 1280x720 and 1280x800

If you accept minor distortion, then you may use following sizes, take from the link in first comment:

```
1920dp x 1080dp
960dp x 720dp
640dp x 480dp
470dp x 320dp
426dp x 320dp
```

Comment: so what should be the size?

Comment: Once again - in given circumstances there is no answer, OP must accept, that his image WILL be distorted.

Comment: is it in this order drawable-hdpi drawable-ldpi drawable-mdpi drawable-xhdpi drawable-xxhdpi

Comment: Of course it's not, it's in descending order. You should REALLY read documentation to understand, what are those -ldpi and -xxhdpi stand for.

Comment: Thanks David, I just checked the table 3 in the link. For Low density (120), ldpi itself there are 4 different sub-divisions with  6 different size for small/normal/Large and Extra large. The folders are classified only based on the dpi not on screen. So how to chose the right size for ldpi ?

Comment: Whatever you choose, there always be a device with distorted aspect ratio. Is it absolutely necessary to have full-screen background, or you can do with a logo on uniform solid color? In that case everything gets MUCH easier.

Comment: yes, I need to have a full screen background. for our discussion lets keep only ldpi. Now We need to just think about the Aspect ratio or the size ?

Comment: Proportional size up or down-scaling does not distort image quality as much as incorrect aspect ratio. Can you post this image somewhere? Maybe a 9-patch is an answer to your problem.

Comment: To summarize, I think you should stick to values in above table.